# wp_mail() not sending email in multisite subdomain

Tags: multisite, email, wp-mail

I have a multisite enabled WordPress configuration.  My main domain is like http://www.example.com, with several subdomains like http://test1.example.com, http://test2.example.com, and so on.

I have written a function in my multisite theme's function file to send some notifications to the multisite users.

```
 $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
 wp_mail('user@example.com', 'Test','Test', $headers);
```

It send the mails as desired when on the main domain, but it does not send any mails when used in subdomain function files.

For example, `user@example.com` is a registered user for http://test1.example.com and he submitting some information in his subdomain page http://test1.example.com/information-form. I want to send that information to that user's email.

**EDIT:** Scenarios:

1. I have a form which have some input fields.
2. Users fills it and upon submitting, using ajax the values transferred to functions file.
3. There is a `add_action('wp_ajax_xxx', 'myFunction');` hook in function page (User is logged in)
4. In `myFunction` the above mentioned code resides.

Comment: And what is the problem you have? "Not working" is very ambiguos. I see in your code that you are trying to set custom `$headers`, are the email sent with incorrect `$headers`? Are the email not sent at all? Please, clarify. Also, can you post the context where you are executing your code (i.e. some [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference))?

Comment: email not sent at all @cybmeta. The same headers are working at the main domain

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the cause and solution to my problem above.

When I send email in sub domain such as http://test1.example.com without a custom "From" address in header, the `wp_mail()` function itself sets the default "From" address as `support@test1.example.com`. This is invalid so the email was not sent.

To solve this, I added a custom "From" email to the header like this:

`$headers[] = 'From: Sender Name <noreply@example.com>';`

This sets a valid email address in the header.

You can also set the same using filters like this:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', function( $email ) {
    return 'noreply@example.com';
});

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', function( $name ) {
    return 'Sender Name';
});
```